# Wrong Colors in render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have stumbled into another problem. For some reason, the camera or the rendered image will come out like this 3D (blue and red) imitations which I never intended. What can I do to fix this issue? 
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib034p3w8qs3hqk/OutHausBackground.blend?dl=0

Comment: that's the stereoscopic 3D rendering option

Comment: I might have activated that by mistake. If you don't mind me asking, where can I find it? Thank you

Comment: yeah I was actually looking for it myself, it took me a few minutes to remember where it was.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks. I'm more used to Maya. Blender feel like another world for me, sometimes I feel like Maya is easier compared to Blender.

Comment: ha, I'm the complete opposite, Im kinda familiar with 3ds, maya just feels like pie menus that keep branching into pie menus. tough their node editor is really robust, that's one thing that I'd like for blender to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the option you accidentally activated, on the render layers tab, the Views section

[image]

just disable the Views checkbox

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you forgot to turn on *Ambient Occlusion*, that happened to me. You can turn it on by going to the *World* tab in the *Properties Window*, then click the checkbox